# Include the last changed date of the source in a ReStructuredText file

Tags: cmake, restructuredtext

I have a project with documentation written in ReStructuredText. The docs are compiled to HTML when the project is built via cmake. It includes a line with a "last changed" date.

I wonder how hard it would be to set this date automatically, as, from time to time, I simply forget to update the last changed date when I edit the docs.

I thought about generating some additional file, like

```
date -d "@$(stat -c %Z Readme.rst)" +"%d.%m.%Y" > lastchange.txt
```

and to reference it in the source like

```
:Date: .. include:: lastchange.txt
```

But would it be possible to achieve such a reference with only RST? Or in a more elegant way? Because doint it like so, it would be necessary to create a "working copy" of the sources in the cmake build directory, because otherwise the reference won't be found. And if I do this, I can as well `sed` the  date into the sources directly.